# How to add where column value != 'Trial' in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select, where-clause

I am facing an issue with a query and the issue is I want to select a value where another column value `!=` "Trial " and I am unable to do this please help me.

Here is my query:

```
$datestart = \DB::table('subscriptions')->where('business_id', $business_id,'payment_transaction_id,""')->Orderby('id','desc')->value('start_date');
```

Comment: Can payment_transaction_id be null?  And if so, do you want to select it when it is?

Answer (score 1):

you need use <> operator

```
->where('column', '<>', 'value')...
```

Comment: $datestart = \DB::table('subscriptions')->where('business_id', $business_id)->WhereNotIn('payment_transaction_id', '<>' ,'Trial')->Orderby('id','desc')->value('start_date');

Still Not working

Comment: @digisoft use `where`, not `WhereNotIn`

Answer (score 0):

you can use '!=' but It is ignoring NULL records so for using '!=' this

```
Model::where('column_name', '!=' ,'value')->orWhereNull('value')->get();
```

So safe is use '<>' this operator,where field not empty

```
Model::where('column_name', '<>' ,'value')->get();
```

Comment: $datestart = \DB::table('subscriptions')->where('business_id', $business_id)->WhereNotIn('payment_transaction_id', '<>' ,'Trial')->Orderby('id','desc')->value('start_date'); Still Not working –

Comment: just use where  instead of whereNotIn

Comment: The whereNotIn method verifies that the given column's value is not contained in the given array.

Comment: There is no difference between `<>` and `!=` in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need this operator <> in where

```
...->where('column_name', '<>' ,'value')->...
```

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.